# C# anagrams of different string length?

Tags: c#, string, linq, lambda, anagram

```
public static bool IsAnagramOf(this string word1, string word2)
{
    return word1.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(word2.OrderBy(x => x));
}
```

I'm currently pulling everything from a large xml file with all english words. I'm then comparing each word against the given string to see if it's an anagram. I'm then storing each correct word and returning them.

However...

I'm wanting to make it so the anagrams do not have to be of equal string length.

For example: "Hello" contains "Hello", "Hell", "He" etc...

Is there anyway to do this that's relatively small in code?

Thanks!

Edit: So including subanagrams as well as anagrams of equal length.

Comment: Check out `String.IndexOf` method.

Comment: But 'Hello' and 'He' aren't anagrams right?

Comment: So you don't really want anagrams, but just words with letters contained in other word. Use `.Contains` or `.Intersection`.

Comment: Anagrams and subanagrams if you will?

Comment: @BartoszKP - good point... also I think it may not be enough - "Help" can't be rearranged into "hell", but straight `Contains`/`Intersect` check will succeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your method should be called `ContainsTheSameSetOfLetters`?

```
public static bool ContainsTheSameSetOfLetters(this string word1, string word2)
{
    var chars = new HashSet<char>(word1);
    return word2.All(x => chars.Contains(x));
}
```

If you care about number of time particular letter is being used, you can use following:

```
public static bool ContainsTheSameSetOfLetters(string word1, string word2)
{
    var chars = word1.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
    return word2.GroupBy(x => x).All(g => chars.ContainsKey(g.Key) && chars[g.Key] >= g.Count());
}
```

Comment: Doesn't account for there being the correct number of duplicate letters though - Hello and Helooooo would return true

Comment: As said above, hello could return hole for example.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another approach, which checks number of times char exists in both strings as well.

Comment: Second answer seems to return everything.

Comment: What do you mean *return everything*?

Comment: I've used it as return (IEnumerable<Word>)_words.GetWords().Where(w => w.Value.ToLower().ContainsTheSameSetOfLetters(_characters.ToLower())); however now "hello" returns every single word it gets compared with.

Comment: OK, There was a typo in variable name. Try it now.

Comment: That works perfect for words with the same word count or a greater word count, however I'm looking for the exact opposite. Something that gets every word up to the length of your input so "Stars" would returns "Rats", "Rat", "Tar", "A", etc.

Comment: You can easily send the parameters in different order?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SequenceEqual, try creating an extension method that checks that the sequence starts with another sequence.